# Proof involving rank of partitioned matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Prove that $$\operatorname{rank}\begin{bmatrix}     A & B  \\     0 & C  \end{bmatrix}\geq \operatorname{rank}A+\operatorname{rank}C.$$
>
> Deduce that the rank of an upper triangular matrix is not less than
>   the number of non-zero diagonal elements.

---

**If I take the column bases of $A$ and $C$, the corresponding columns of the bigger matrix are Linearly Independent.**

This above idea is fairly intuitive and very helpful, but I am unable to write it down as a formal proof. Could someone help me express it in a clean and presentable form?

---

For the deduction part, I see that any Upper Triangular Matrix can be expressed as  $     \begin{bmatrix}     A & B  \\     0 & C   \\     \end{bmatrix}$.

Now, if I could show that:

*rank* of $A \geq$ *number of non-zero diagonal elements in A* $\ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ -(1)$

*rank* of $C \geq$ *number of non-zero diagonal elements in C* $\ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ -(2)$

then the deduction logically follows.

The thing I find strange is that $A$ and $C$ are both themselves Upper Triangular Matrices. So effectively, both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are exactly what I started out to deduce in the first place. This basically puts me in a loop. I seem to be missing something and would like some help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint.* Let $r,s$ be the ranks of $A$ and $C$ respectively, $\{Ax_1,\ldots,Ax_r\}$ be a basis of the column space of $A$ and $\{Cy_1,\ldots,Cy_s\}$ be a basis of the column space of $C$. Now show that the vectors
$$
\pmatrix{Ax_1\\ 0},\ldots,\pmatrix{Ax_r\\ 0},\pmatrix{By_1\\ Cy_1},\ldots,\pmatrix{By_s\\ Cy_s}
$$
are linearly independent and they all reside in the image of $\pmatrix{A&B\\ 0&C}$.

Comment: For Linear Independence,  $\alpha_1\begin {pmatrix}
Ax_1\\
0\\
\end {pmatrix} +\cdots +\alpha_r\begin {pmatrix}
Ax_r\\
0\\
\end {pmatrix} +\alpha_{r+1}\begin {pmatrix}
By_1\\
Cy_1\\
\end {pmatrix} +\alpha_{r+s}\begin {pmatrix}
By_s\\
Cy_s\\
\end {pmatrix} =0\Rightarrow\alpha_{r+1}Cy_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{r+s}Cy_{s}=0\Rightarrow\alpha_{r+1},\ldots,\alpha_{r+s}=0\Rightarrow\alpha_{1}Ax_{1}+\cdots+\alpha_{r}Ax_{r}=0\Rightarrow\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{r}=0 $

Comment: To show $\begin {pmatrix}
Ax_i\\
0\\
\end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix}
A&B\\
0&C\\
\end {pmatrix}x$ ,take $x=\begin {pmatrix}
x_i\\
0
\end {pmatrix}$ . To show $\begin {pmatrix}
By_j\\
Cy_j\\
\end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix}
A&B\\
0&C\\
\end {pmatrix}y$ ,take $y=\begin {pmatrix}
0\\
y_j
\end {pmatrix}$. Is my approach fine?

Comment: @s0ulr3aper07, kindly show the inequality part, it seems that the rank of the bigger matrix is $r+s$.